# Custom menu items and layout in react material select

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I am using material select component in my react application. Can i specify the layout of menu items to next to each other and wrap to new line ? Desired componnent should look like this:

[image]

Comment: I think you can use menu items component, check this one https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#customized-menuitem

Comment: Yes, the point is, how do i layout this menu items to look like in the picture.